# Map Reduce - How to sum and get the highest value

Tags: python, mapreduce, bigdata

i am learning Map Reduce... but I have not experience with Python... I am trying to this:
Sum contracts numbers of woman if the city is the same.
Get the city with highest number of Woman contracts.
(I am using Dumbo)
This is my Code:

```
import csv

from dumbo import main


def load_contratos_mapper(contratos_files):
    contratos = {}
    try:
        # Read table - medal|prize|country|year
        with open(contratos_files) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', doublequote=False)
            reader.next()
            for line in reader:
                contratos[(line[0], line[1], line[2], lin[3], line[4])] = line[5]

    except:
        pass

    return contratos


class Join_contratos_reduce:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contratos = load_contratos('./Contratos_por_municipio.csv')

    def __call__(self, key, values):
        try:
            values.groupby([1])[5].sum()
            yield values

        except:
            pass

def runner(job):
    inout_opts = [("inputformat", "text"), ("outputformat", "text")]
    o1 = job.additer(load_contratos_mapper, Join_contratos_reduce, opts=inout_opts)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(runner)
```

Comment: wjhere is the main func code? and what is job?

Comment: this is all the code.... I am follow a guide so I have not too much idea, but i run the code like this:

dumbo start practica7.py -hadoop /usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hadoop -hadooplib /usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hadoop-mapreduce/ -python /usr/bin/python -input /user/root/in/Comunidades_y_provincias.csv -output /user/root/out/ \ -file ./Contratos_por_municipio.csv